# AppAuth iOS Share access token between two apps

Tags: ios, appauth

I Currently have a swift application that uses AppAuth to sign in and authorise API calls to the backend server.

I want to develop a second application, but have it share access tokens: i.e if you are already signed into the first app then you do not need to sign into the second app - it just logs you in; and vice versa.

Is this possible?and if so what steps are involved? I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and Swift 5

Comment: Use keychain sharing via an application group.

Comment: Paulw11, thanks for the reply. So do I need to setup both application group and keychain sharing capabilities in both apps? Also, is the service parameter of the keychain required or just an accessGroup string? Many thanks.